# Do LLMs based on a diffusion model (as opposed to an autoregressive model) exist?

Tags: large-language-models, diffusion-models

Is there a such thing (described in title), at least in research papers (not actual models)?

So far all LLMs that I know are autoregressive models.

Comment: The question you want to ask is "Do LLMs based on a diffusion model (as opposed to an autoregressive model) exist?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a false dichotomy. Most diffusion models, including Dalle 2 and 3, already are transformers.

However, assuming you meant to ask if any language models use diffusion as opposed to a GPT, the answer is yes. For example, see this recent paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.09515